# Python CSV Rewrite a line

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a .csv file with some infos like:

```
0   Name    Telephone   Description 27/11/2017  21:02
```

and I want to rewrite only one line with three other columns like this:

```
0   Name    Telephone   Descripton  27/11/2017  21:02   AnotherDate  AnotherTime    Value
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Could you give me some context please.

Comment: You can't rewrite a line without reading the whole file and overwriting it

Comment: I have a program who writerow with id, name, tel, date, time I get this data as an input log and i want to add the output log like another three other columns

Comment: Yea, I know about read the whole file to overwrite, but i don't know how can I overwrite just one file row.